# I can't find where I'm dividing by zero , as I'm getting 'inf' as O/P for I/P

Tags: c++14

This is the code for finding incircle radius of a sphere inscribed in an irregular tetrahedron,
please do help with finding where there is an error....

Imean how to remove that inf part, and do tell if there's any error in implementation part of formulae.
As i'm getting wrong answer for second case....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double cosine (int a, int b, int c)
{
double temp = ( a*a + b*b - c*c ) / (2.0 * a * b);
return (temp);
}

double area (int a, int b, int c)
{
double s = (a + b + c )/2 ; 
double ar = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
return(ar);
}

int main()
{ 
long int t = 0, T = 0;
scanf("%ld", &T);

while(t++ < T)
{
    int AB, BC, AC, AD, BD, CD;
    double cos1, cos2, cos3,ar1,ar2,ar3,ar4;

    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", &AB, &AC, &AD, &BC, &BD, &CD);

    cos1 = cosine(AD, BD, AB);
    cos2 = cosine(BD, CD, BC);
    cos3 = cosine(CD, AD, AC);
    ar1 = area(AD, BD, AB);
    ar2 = area(BD, CD, BC);
    ar3 = area(CD, AD, AC);
    ar4 = area(AB, BC, AC);
    double temp = sqrt( 1 + 2 * cos1 * cos2 * cos3 - cos1*cos1 - cos2*cos2 - 
    cos3*cos3);
    double vol = AD * BD * CD * temp / 6;
    double answer = 3*vol/(ar1+ar2+ar3+ar4);
    printf("%0.4lf\n", answer); 
}
return 0;
 }
```

Input

```
2
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

1000 1000 1000 5 5 6

Output

```
inf
1.6474
```

Comment: Thanks ... after debugging, found that the problem was in double s = (a + b + c )/2 ;....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double s = (a + b + c)/2` first calculates `(a + b + c)/2` and *then* converts the result to `double`. `a`, `b`, and `c` are `int`, so this is integer division which discards the remainder, and if `a+b+c` is `1`, you get `0` as the result. Eventually you end up dividing by zero.

When you change to `(a + b + c)/2.0` (the brackets aren't necessary), you use real division, because it converts `a + b + c` to `double` first.

I honestly think "`/` is both integer division and floating point division" is one of the worse things in C and languages which inherited from it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the source code from:

```
double s = (a + b + c)/2;
```

to:

```
double s = (a + b + c)/(2.0);
```

And the problem was solved.

But I'm unable to understand why without parenthesis and decimal point, it still showed `inf`.